# Can Every Embedding of the Sphere be continuously deformed back into the Sphere?

Tags: manifolds, geometric-topology

The Sphere, $S^2$, has lots of homemorphic embeddings into $\mathbb{R^3}$. But can every single one be deformed back into a sphere from within $\mathbb{R^3}$?

In other words, does each bi-continuous injective $f:S^2 \to \mathbb{R^3}$ have an isotopy $g:f(S^2)\times [0,1] \to \mathbb{R^3}$, where $g(f(S^2)\times\{1\}) = \{(x,y,z): x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1\}$?

How about for other manifolds embedded into other euclidean spaces?

Comment: Do you require $g$ to be defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^3$? If not, then yes of course $g$ exists: just take $f^{-1}$ composed with the embedding you specified for $A$.

Comment: Thanks, I messed up with the formulation...g should be an isotopy.

Comment: Your edited question is still a mess since you did not define isotopy correctly. But with the correct definition the answer is negative because of wild spheres.

Comment: Incidentally, in smooth category, any two embeddings are isotopic by a generalization of Schoenfly's theorem.

Comment: What is wrong with my statement of Isotopy? I am looking at Hatcher who says a homotopy is any continuous $F:X \times I \to Y$. Wikipedia says an Isotopy is a homotopy for which each $F(-,t)$ is an embedding. Edit: would it make more sense to ask for $g : S^2 \times I \to \mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: @DanielMourad: Yes, it is a continuous map $S^2\times I\to R^3$ satisfying certain properties which you did not list correctly.

Comment: To address the question in you latter paragraph, there is an entire branch of topology dedicated to studying the isotopy classes of embeddings $S^1 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^3$. This is called "knot theory".